# Android: can't get javascript to work on WebView even with setJavaScriptEnabled(true)

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm a complete noob to Android and this is just a simple test. [Based it on this tutorial.](http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=uVqp1zcMfbE&vq=hd720#t=68)

Here goes the HelloWebApp.java

```
package com.company.something;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class HelloWebApp extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

And this is from res/layout/main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<WebView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Plus this is all I changed on the Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".HelloWebApp"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

As for the javascript, I've tried everything. Complicated, simple, inside the body at the bottom, in a button, on the head. Nothing works. The html works fine.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You missed the part in the tutorial where he adds

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

right after adding

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

The [JavaDoc for this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebChromeClient(android.webkit.WebChromeClient)) says:

> Sets the chrome handler. This is an implementation of WebChromeClient for use in handling Javascript dialogs, favicons, titles, and the progress. This will replace the current handler.

Comment: Thanks no.good.at.coding. Although that should be my name. ;-)

Comment: One thing not mentioned in the tutorial are the imports: import android.webkit.WebChromeClient; import android.webkit.WebView; . You can hover over the code underlined in red and you'll get some options to fix it. The first one will be the imports.

Comment: obrigado o que faltou aqui foi isso}
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7561674/1818089,

along with

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

you need to enable DOM storage

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score -2):

just add

```
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
```

in YourApp.java