# Webview Application Download doesnt work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

In my website there are some downloadable contents. I have created a webview application out of that website using android studio. In my application when i click those downloadable contents nothing happens, it doesn't get downloaded. but if I use that website from moblile's browser it gets downloaded. Then What is the problem with my android application ?

Comment: `What is the problem with my android application` you likely did not implement download functionality. WebView can't download from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
            long contentLength) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}
});
```

Comment: hey my codes are in the following answer . Could you tell me where should I include your codes ?

Comment: add this under 
mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

Answer (score 0):

Please Add this code to enable javascript in your webview. Because some javascript is not load in webview.

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

For more details follow below link

[Enable Javascript in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548172/javascript-not-working-in-android-webview/48400556#48400556)

Hope this will be help you