# I am Trying to create a webview activity but the whole website is not loaded

Tags: android, android-webview

Recently i developed a Webapp in codeignitor(php). Now i am trying to convert into  `WebviewActivity` for Android.

Activity when open in Android browser

it works fine

[image: it works fine]

but when opened in Webview activity App i get this

Half side of Website blank

[image: Half side of Website blank]
Methods i tried

- `webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() )`
- `webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(this))`

i have been stuck on this problem from several hours. searched everywhere but did not find the right answer

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the xml of your view?

Comment: enable javascript for your webview. Might be because of that

Comment: Can you please put your `WebView` configuration from your code?

Comment: firstly, don't treat WebView as full-functional browser. It is not. Probably your site content is generated depending on web browser's user-agent. Try changing your WebView's user-agent to the one android browser is using

Comment: Some are javascript are not load in android webview. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548172/javascript-not-working-in-android-webview/48400556#48400556 to load js in webview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go...try this

```
<WebView
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>



    WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    browser.loadUrl(url);

    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```