# loading html/javascript via webView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have the following script that I need to show in a browser. I tried loading 
with WebView loadData and loadDataWithBaseURL but with no success (empty view).
I probably miss something with the MIME, Encoding, etc.

```
<head>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'/>
<script type='text/javascript'     src='http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt_mobile.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>eval(window.location.search.substring(1));googletag.cmd.push(function(){googletag.defineSlot('/7047/AppCamoli_Iphone_Transition_Splash',[320,480],'div-gpt-ad-2935936626049-0').addService(googletag.pubads());googletag.enableServices();});</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding: 0;">
<div id='div-gpt-ad-2935936626049-0'>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        document.getElementById('div-gpt-ad-2935936626049-0').id='div-gpt-ad-2935936626049-0';googletag.cmd.push(function(){googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-2935936626049-0')});
    </script>
</div>
</body>
```

The code I have is followed:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web);

    try {
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        boolean typeURL = i.getBooleanExtra("urlType", true);
        String url = i.getStringExtra("url");
        if (typeURL)
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        else {
            //String html = "<html><body>You scored <b>hello world</b> points.</body></html>";
            String html = "<html><head><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'/><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt_mobile.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>eval(window.location.search.substring(1));googletag.cmd.push(function(){googletag.defineSlot('/7047/AppCamoli_Iphone_Transition_Splash',[320,480],'div-gpt-ad-2935936626049-0').addService(googletag.pubads());googletag.enableServices();});</script></head><body style='margin:0; padding: 0;'><div id='div-gpt-ad-2935936626049-0'><script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('div-gpt-ad-2935936626049-0').id='div-gpt-ad-2935936626049-0';googletag.cmd.push(function(){googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-2935936626049-0')});</script></div></body></html>";
            //webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/javascript", "UTF-8", null);
            webView.loadData(html, "text/javascript", "UTF-8");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("webView","failed to load URL");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This results in an empty webView.

Thanks,

Simon

Comment: post some of your Android code....and more importantly, post information what what errors you got...."no success" don't provide much info

Comment: I have edited the question to add the code and the result.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try modifying the WebSettings and enabling JavaScript?

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110916/android-cant-get-javascript-to-work-on-webview-even-with-setjavascriptenabled) link.

"You missed the part in the tutorial where he adds

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

right after adding

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);"
```